# post timestamp in web_submit_data itemdata in loadrunner

Tags: json, http-post, unix-timestamp, loadrunner, hyperion

In our hyperion application, we have a explore button.
Here is its post:

```
web_submit_data("explorer", //FIXME: id vlaue parameter
    "Action=https://{host_url}/raframework/browse/explorer", 
    "Method=POST", 
    "TargetFrame=", 
    "RecContentType=application/x-json", 
    "Referer=https://{host_url}/workspace/index.jsp?framed=true", 
    "Snapshot=t19.inf", 
    "Mode=HTML",
    ITEMDATA, 
    "Name=class", "Value=com.hyperion.tools.cds.explorer.ExplorerView", ENDITEM, 
    "Name=id", "Value=EV1390418511260", ENDITEM, //"Name=id", "Value=EV1389926310921", ENDITEM, 

    LAST);
```

This `EV1390418511260` is from

```
this._rstExplorerViewId = "EV" + (new Date()).getTime();
```

from the loaded module.js file I guess, which is Unix time stamp

I tried `lr_save_timestamp("timestamp", LAST );` to correlate value of id with Unix time stamp. like `Value=EV{timestamp}`. The request is being posted but the response body has

```
Content-Length: 0 
X-ORACLE-BPMUI-CSRF: false
```

I want to try

```
typedef long time_t;
time_t t;
```

and correlate something like `Value=EV{time(&t)}` but here it converts to url encode and takes ascii values of those special chars.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you using C code to replace the functionality of built in capability to LoadRunner?

See **web_save_timestamp_param()** for the number of milliseconds since Jan 1, 1970.

```
web_save_timestamp_param("tStamp", LAST );

web_submit_data("explorer", 
...
ITEMDATA, 
"Name=class", "Value=com.hyperion.tools.cds.explorer.ExplorerView", ENDITEM, 
"Name=id", "Value=EV{tStamp}", ENDITEM, 
LAST);
```

if this is your first trip into the Hyperion universe I would heartily suggest you find the most experienced LoadRunner professional available anywhere in the nation to support your efforts.  You do not need to be struggling with tool use while at the same time working in one of the more difficult environments for any performance testing tool.   Assuming you get someone who has been succesful with Hyperion recently, no matter what your organization spends (even as high as $300 per hour or more) it will be money well spent versus struggling with both tool mechanics and testing of the environment

Comment: yes this is the first time I am doing hyperion. I have used `lr_save_timestamp` which is same as `web_save_timestamp_param`. I tried as you suggested too but I get this below response which is same as before and server is not accepting it or returning anything. `HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Date: Wed, 22 Jan 2014 22:12:14 GMT
Server: Oracle-Application-Server-11g
Content-Length: 0
X-ORACLE-BPMUI-CSRF: false
X-ORACLE-DMS-ECID: 00iJmmnLUkQ66Uw5oFL6iY0000zK000F7m
X-Powered-By: Servlet/2.5 JSP/2.1
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/plain
Content-Language: en`

Comment: Do you mean lr_save_datetime()?  lr_save_timestamp shows as an unresolved symbol on my system

Comment: Here it is in LR help, `Utility Functions and C Language Reference > Utility Functions: C Language (lr) > Alphabetical Listing > lr_save_timestamp` and `lr_save_timestamp("timestmp", LAST );` which saves the current timestamp to a parameter in Unix format **LR11.52**

Comment: It looks like they took the web item and simply made it available in the general library for all virtual user types.   In either case, unless you are explicitly checking for expected results on every step then the odds are near certainty that the issue is with a request earlier than the one you are having issues with.   If you simply accept an HTTP 200 and continue (or have continue on error without error handling code) then you likely have an out of context request which is throwing a catastrophic error

Comment: Thank you, I figured that, header was carrying some other additional tokens like asserttoken and other oracle tokens. I have correlated them. Now fiddling with folder and file structure. I assume, you must be Hyperion-loadrunner guy, do you mind sharing your code snippets to handle folder and file structure of hyperion...? appreciate..

Comment: I have worked in the Hyperion Universe before.  Any code I write is the property of my clients.  As such, it is not subject to being shared without their written permission.